# How to select statement to avoid duplicated item

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Can I know how to select one item without duplicates? Here's the things.

I have a same value on first column (Eg: `studentid = 123`) on student table.

And the other column is in accounts table has same value (`123`).

What should I do if I wanted to select just one value in student table inner join accounts table? I use `distinct`, but it still give two values because of other columns have different values.

Current query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SAS_Student.SASI_MatricNo
    ,SAS_Student.SASI_Name
    ,SAS_Student.SASI_PgId
    ,SAS_Student.SASI_ICNo
    ,SAS_Student.SASI_CurSem
    ,SAS_AccountsDetails.TransTempCode
    ,SAS_AccountsDetails.TempAmount
    ,SAS_AccountsDetails.TempPaidAmount
    ,SAS_AccountsDetails.PostStatus
    ,SAS_AccountsDetails.Ref1
    ,SAS_AccountsDetails.NoKelompok
    ,SAS_AccountsDetails.NoWarran
    ,SAS_AccountsDetails.AmaunWarran
    ,SAS_AccountsDetails.noAkaunPelajar
    ,SAS_AccountsDetails.StatusBayaran
FROM SAS_AccountsDetails
INNER JOIN SAS_sponsorinvoice ON sas_sponsorinvoice.creditref1 = SAS_AccountsDetails.ref1
    OR sas_sponsorinvoice.creditref1 = SAS_AccountsDetails.refcode
INNER JOIN sas_student ON sas_sponsorinvoice.creditref = sas_student.sasi_matricno
WHERE sas_sponsorinvoice.batchcode = 'B000000000000303'
```

---

```
SASI_MatricNo SASI_Name                SASI_PgId SASI_ICNo      SASI_CurSem TransTempCode        TempAmount TempPaidAmount PostStatus Ref1  NoKelompok NoWarran AmaunWarran noAkaunPelajar StatusBayaran
"160553"      "RATHIYMALER A/P MANIAM" "32"      "911229086066"           2 "TRT000000000000054"          0              0 "Ready"    "001" ""         ""                 0 ""             ""
"160553"      "RATHIYMALER A/P MANIAM" "32"      "911229086066"           2 ""                            0              0 "Posted"   "001" ""         ""                 0 ""             ""
"160553"      "RATHIYMALER A/P MANIAM" "32"      "911229086066"           2 "TRT000000000000019"          0              0 "Ready"    "001" ""         ""                 0 ""             ""
```

Comment: Give some sample data and expected output. How do you choose which record you want included in the result set?

Comment: show us what u have tried, your tables, query and expected output

Comment: also is this related to mysql or postgresql?

Comment: If you want only one row per studentid, how do you chose which one?

Comment: `DISTINCT` removes **duplicate rows**. If you have two rows that have the same values in two columns but different values in the other columns, which row should `DISTINCT` keep? It's not a decision `SQL` can do; it doesn't remove any of them and returns both.

Comment: @Farid you need to edit your question instead of posting the same in comments

Comment: So, which line would you like to see in the result?

Comment: Would like to see just one output instead of three .

Comment: Which of the records do you expect? Which `TransTempCode`, for example, and why?

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution is to add to the end of the query

```
Order By --(condition to bring the desired record to the top of the list)--
Limit 1
```

Which will return just the first row of the resultset.